# Will it degrade my SSD life if I use a dualboot of Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

I read somewhere that SSDs weren't made to be partitioned, and I have no idea about the validity of that affirmation.

I have just installed Windows on a Samsung 840 EVO 250Gb SSD, and I want to create a partition in it to install Ubuntu. Will it somehow degrade my SSD life if I have this dualboot setup?

Comment: Although not directly related to your question, you may also want to consider whether running one of your OSes in a VM would be a better solution.  Having to reboot your entire system to switch between OSes is inconvenient, to say the least.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you heard may have been valid for some of the earliest solid-state storage devices, but does not apply to modern SSDs at the end-user level.  First, modern flash memory can sustain many more erase/write cycles than earlier technology.  Second, the SSD's firmware will perform [wear-leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Wear_leveling) across all the drive's flash memory, including the drive's spare memory *and the memory used to store static files which rarely or never change.*

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry about it. That's like worrying whether using your car will reduce its life before driving to the store to get a soda. Who cares? The reason you have things is so that you can use them. Altering your behavior because of microscopic affects on product life is just not worth it.

Comment: Truly, premature optimization is the root of all evil.